# Catching Exceptions of all Futures/Callables in an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an `ExecutorService` containing a number of running `Callables`. I have a list of `Futures` for these `Callables`. I want to find out as soon as possible if one of the `Callables` throws an `Exception`. All `Callables` are equally likely to throw an `Exception`. The `Callables` usually run for several hours.

The usual approach seems to be to use the `Future.get()` method. However, you can only use this for one `Future`. If another `Future` throws an `Exception` I am not notified. So I was thinking of writing a loop that checks the `Future.isDone()` method for all Futures and sleeping for some time after each iteration. However, this approach is not really nice, so I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why not wrap your callables and handle each error in wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), wrap your executor with it and then calling [`#take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#take()) will return the first completed result.

Example:

```
CompletionService<Object> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
//submit a bunch of tasks
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i-> completionService.submit(Object::new));
//Wait for any of them to complete, wrap in a loop to take them all
completionService.take();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) for your use-case

```
static CompletableFuture<Object> anyOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)
```

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when any of the
>   given CompletableFutures complete, with the same result. Otherwise, if
>   it completed exceptionally, the returned CompletableFuture also does
>   so, with a CompletionException holding this exception as its cause. 
>   If no CompletableFutures are provided, returns an incomplete
>   CompletableFuture.

You should store all your futures in a list. `

Now

```
List<CompletableFuture<?>> futureList = // all futures;
while(futureList.size()>0){
    CompletableFuture<?> completed = CompletableFuture.anyOf(futureList); //convert futureList to array
    if(completed.isCompletedExceptionally()){
       // first future that completed with an exception
    }else{
       //future completed without exception, store the result or process
       futureList.remove(completed); // remove it from the incomplete list
    }
}
```

You may obtain a `CompletableFuture` like

```
final CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
         //...long running...
         return "returnVal";
      },
   executor); //here executor is your executor pool
```

If you don't want to use explicit executor pool

```
    final CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
             //...long running...
             return "returnVal";
          });
```

However, in this case it will be submitted to the [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).commonPool()

Comment: This answer sort of glosses over the critical step of obtaining a `CompletableFuture` when all you have is a `Future`.